# Encrypted comms between devices on LAN

Tags: protocol-design, reference-request, authenticated-encryption, embedded

I'm trying to encrypt a protocol that shares data between devices on a local area network (i.e.no connection to the internet). I don't want to use predefined keys because they're too easy to read from the firmware. What I'd like is for the devices to dynamically setup an encrypted network which prevents anyone reverse engineering the protocol. Someone once told me that when it comes to encryption "never roll your own" so I'm wondering what's out there.

The requirements are:

1. Must work over Ethernet (minimum of 10MB/s).
2. Must not require internet access.
3. Must not have hardcoded or otherwise predictable keys, and keys must be revocable/replaceable (from [HedgeMage](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/124/hedgemage)).
4. Devices can be added and removed from the network (note all devices are supplied by us).
5. Messages can be sent unicast and multicast (between multiple devices).
6. Encryption should be immune to replay attacks.
7. Encryption should be capable of being run on an ARM CPU with only basic HW cryptographic support (i.e. solution can't rely on any specialised HW).
8. No scope to add additional HW like smart card readers.

Does anything like this already exist?

Comment: *Must not have a key that can be read from the firmware*, keys have to be stored somewhere. What are acceptable options here? For example, we could require something like a smart-card reader on each device and a smart card to be inserted in order to join the encrypted network.

Comment: Can it be possible for other devices not owned by you to join the network?

Comment: Clarifying question: when you say "must not have a key that can be read from the firmware", do you mean "must not have any hardcoded keys that are compromised by someone buying another device of the same model and reversing it" or "must store its key in a hardware crypto module"?

FWIW, in my design, that parameter would be more like: "no hardcoded or otherwise predictable keys, and keys must be revocable/replaceable." Unless, of course, the use case warranted a hardware crypto module per device.

Comment: "with only basic HW cryptographic support." I'm not entirely sure that I understand what that means. Imagine going to a car dealer and ordering a "basic car".

Comment: Updated to answer your comments. When I talk about not having keys I'm just aware that hardcoding a key in the SW can be reverse engineered. I don't know if there are solutions that don't require keys at all, that's the point of the question!

Comment: Could you clarify your goals? That is - from whom are you planning to hide the info by encryption?  First time I read your question, I thought of SSL/TLS protocol but then I realised I was not sure what level of communication you wanted to get encrypted..   If you want ALL the network traffic to be encrypted - it's one task, if, say, it suffices to encrypt the tcp/ip traffic - that's a completely different task. Please elaborate on this.   PS: l strongly agree with "never roll your own" statement.

Comment: Our devices will be bought by customers who don't want the data they put on them hacked by someone else. Note that although there may not be an internet connection the LAN may have a Wi-Fi access point so can be accessed from outside. I'm talking about encrypting one or more protocols we use to share data between the devices. The problem I have with SSL/TLS is that it requires an internet connection to get new certificates. What happens in a few years when they expire?

Comment: (end of line via two spaces does not work for me for some reason)  Right. A bit clearer but still not clear :) 1. A side note: "encrypting one or more protocols" - surely, you encrypt data, not protocols.  2. "requires an internet connection to get new certificates" - certificates are for authentication (i.e. to prove that device X is device X and not someone else), you never mentioned  authentication, only encryption - in which case certificates are not something to worry about.  3. Are your devices capable of securely storing a secret key? Security module,tamper-resistant memory or suchlike?

Comment: 1. Whatever. 2. You mentioned SSL/TLS which, as I understand it, require certificates. 3. If they were I would have said so.